# Is there a way to block an user from acessing PUT, POST and DELETE resources in resteasy?

Tags: java, rest, authorization, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a lot of methods in my program and also a lot of users. How would I do, to make a specific user profile only be allowed to access the methods marked with @GET in RestEasy ?

**UPDATE**

I have some users profile like admin, owner, manager, employee and demonstration.

I would like to deny all operations but GET to user whose profile is Demonstration. The way I block some users from performing some methods is simply checking to which profile they belong (IF).

Comment: How do you identify such a user? Please provide more details on what a "user profile" is in your application and how such a user profile interacts with your resources.

Answer (score 2):

If your system already defines users and roles and you can implement standard authentication and authorization using JAAS, then you could use Jboss security annotations to secure your methods. Please see this link for more details -

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html

Comment: Looks useful, but they say: NOTE!!! Do not turn on this switch if you are using EJBs. The EJB container will provide this functionality instead of Resteasy.
I'm using EJBs, so looks like we dropped into another question...

Comment: That's even good news. You can use the standard authorization mechanism that comes with EJB3. Once you setup Jaas authentication, you could use 'PermitAll' and 'RolesAllowed' annotations to control access to your methods.            http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html

Answer (score 0):

In front of a REST service, you can also add a reverse HTTP proxy (like Apache) and use the authentication provider you want (LDAP or others).

Example:

```
<Location /myService/>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName Foo
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.acme.org/dc=acme,dc=org?cn
   <LIMIT POST PUT DELETE>
     require ldap-group cn=employee,dc=acme,dc=org
   </LIMIT>
</Location>
```